# difficulty in saving the trained model for my CNN sentence classifer at test it on a single instance later by loading the model

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning, pickle, theano, convolution

I am using the cnn text classification written by [Yoon Kim](https://github.com/yoonkim/CNN_sentence) for sentiment analysis. This code applies cross validation to check the quality of learned model. However, I want to save the learned weights and biases, so I can apply the learned model on new instances one by one for the prediction purpose. I appreciate if someone provides an example of how I can do that. I know that I should use pickle load and dumb to do that, but I am not sure exactly which part of the code I should use them I want to have a separate test.py file so I can only test the trained model on a test sample without training the model again. how I should save and then predict based on saved model?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need pickle for some special reason. You can easily use numpy's save and load functions:

```
#saving the parameters
params = classifier.params
np.save("net_parameters", params)

#loading the parameters
params = np.load("net_parameters.npy")
classifier.params = params
```

Comment: can you please explain more about how the code should change, if we want to save the trained model and load it in the test time to predict the sentiment for one instance only?